# how to turn an entire Tr in a actionlink

Tags: c#, html-helper, actionlink

I want to transform this tr a actionlink like this:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           @Html.ActionLink("
            <tr style="height:70px; padding-right: 2%;">
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EVEN_IX_NOME)
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EVEN_DESCRICAO)
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EVEN_CONTATO)
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EVEN_EMAIL)
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EVEN_RESPONSAVEL)
                </td>
            </tr>","Options", new{id = item.EVEN_ID})
        }
```

Is it possible? How can i do this? I am new to asp.net mvc

Comment: HTML does not allow that.

Comment: You can't - `ActionLink` generates a hyperlink - you can't make an entire row a hyperlink.  You can make each cell _contain_ a hyperlink or do some fancy JavaScript/jQuery/CSS to do something when someone clicks in the row, but those are much more advanced that just wrapping it with a `ActionLink` call

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks that helped a lot